# Lombok and builder annotation

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I'm working a java maven project that uses another 3rd party java maven module.

This module makes use of Lombok.

I'm compiling the 3rd party maven module from source using `mvn clean install`.

When I call a class from the 3rd party maven module in my java project I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.arc.Reflections.invokeMethod(Reflections.java:95)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method builder() is undefined for the type ThirdPartyClass
```

I've tried adding the following to both maven projects, but it hasnt made any difference:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>delombok</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>delombok</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/delombok</outputDirectory>
                            <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                            <formatPreferences>
                                <javaLangAsFQN>skip</javaLangAsFQN>
                            </formatPreferences>
                            <verbose>false</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- This is for delomboking also your tests sources. <execution> <id>test-delombok</id> 
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase> <goals> <goal>testDelombok</goal> </goals> 
                        <configuration> <verbose>false</verbose> </configuration> </execution> -->
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I'm not using an IDE to compile and run the java project - just using a terminal.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: how have you added the dependency on this module? Also, you don't need to delombok if the build is successfully generating the jar

Comment: Yes I have a dependency on the 3rd party module, and this module has a dependency on Lombok.